# Erro de violação de chave estrangeira apenas em inclusão via API, via a banco inserção está correta

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, sql-insert, chave-estrangeira

Tenho uma api em .NET Core que se conecta à um banco Postgres usando Entity Framework.

Para cada tabela que precisa fazer alguma inserção eu tenho o modelo com os campos certos (criadas na mão pois tive problema com o scaffold).

E a tabela que está me gerando o problema se chama **tbatributos**, nela tenho um campo chamado **tbaaditivos_idaditivo** que se referencia com a tabela **tbaditivo** no campo **idaditivo**.

Antes eu tinha criado sem definir se aceitava null ou não, porem, depois do primeiro erro, exclui o campo e a FK e recriei da seguinte forma.

```
ALTER TABLE tbatributo ADD COLUMN tbaditivo_idtbaditivo INTEGER NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbatributo
ADD FOREIGN KEY (tbaditivo_idtbaditivo) 
REFERENCES public.tbaditivo(idtbaditivo)
```

Feito isso foi possível criar registros via banco sem o campo idtbaditivo como pode-se ver na seguinte imagem:
[image: comando de inserção na tabela tbatributos definindo tbaditivo_idtbaditivo como null executando corretamente via pgadmin]

Porem, o erro na inserção via api permanece.

Não tenho migrations nem nada pois não utilizei scaffold-dbcontext nem add-migrations.

Quando testei excluindo a chave, o erro sumiu e a inserção ocorreu de forma correta, porem, não é isso que eu quero.

[image: Imagem do erro PostgresException: 23503: insert or update on table tbatributo violates foreign key constraint tbatributo_tbaditivo_idtbaditivo_fkey aparecendo na tela do visual studio na linha _context.saveChanges"]

**Create da tabela tbatributo**

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbatributo
(
    idtbatributo integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tbatributo_idtbatributo_seq'::regclass),
    valortbatributo character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    datatbatributo character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tbsituacao_idtbsituacao integer NOT NULL,
    tbcampo_idtbcampo integer NOT NULL,
    tbcontrato_idtbcontrato integer NOT NULL,
    tbaditivo_idtbaditivo integer,
    CONSTRAINT tbatributo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idtbatributo),
    CONSTRAINT tbatributo_tbaditivo_idtbaditivo_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tbaditivo_idtbaditivo)
        REFERENCES public.tbaditivo (idtbaditivo) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT tbatributo_tbcontrato_idtbcontrato_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tbcontrato_idtbcontrato)
        REFERENCES public.tbcontrato (idcontrato) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.tbatributo
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Minha classe tbatributo na api:

```
 public class tbatributo : BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public int idtbatributo { get; set; }
    public string valortbatributo { get; set; }
    public string datatbatributo { get; set; }
    public int tbsituacao_idtbsituacao { get; set; }
    public int tbcampo_idtbcampo { get; set; }
    public int tbcontrato_idtbcontrato { get; set; }
    public int tbaditivo_idtbaditivo { get; set; }
}
```

**Na controller:**

```
  [EnableCors]
    [HttpPost("InsereCampos")]
    public IEnumerable<tbatributo> InsereCampos()
    {
        List<tbatributo> _atributos = new List<tbatributo>();
        List<tbatributo> atributos = new List<tbatributo>();
    string body;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    _atributos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<tbatributo>>(body);
    foreach (tbatributo item in _atributos)
    {
        atributos.Add(_repositorio.Add(item));
    }
    return (atributos);
}
```

**No repositório:**

```
   [EnableCors]
    public T Add(T entidade)
    { 
        entidades.Add(entidade);

    _contexto.SaveChanges();
    return entidade;
}
```

[Aqui tenho os arquivos de **repositório**, **startup.cs**, **program.cs** e a **controller do tbatributo**](https://agenciabaciaspcj-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gabriela_mattos_agencia_baciaspcj_org_br/EnT7mncCZP9BuiT5MbKOdcIBwTwf64_vt-O5ejTfyF6Mig?e=ZtCZSs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu modelo. `tbaditivo_idtbaditivo` é um INTEIRO e, por isso, o valor default é 0 (zero). Como não existe a entrada com id = 0, vc recebe este erro da base de dados. Altere `tbaditivo_idtbaditivo` para nullable e será possível inserir um `tbatributo` sem `tbaditivo_idtbaditivo`.

Altere então o seu modelo para `public int? tbaditivo_idtbaditivo { get; set; }`. Note a `?` junto do tipo da propriedade.